# how to proceed with the geode-benchmark？

Tags: java, apache, geode

I downloaded Apache geode at GitHub,I'm taking the geode benchmark now. Do you have the following questions that can help me out? Or could you tell me how to proceed with the geode-benchmark ?
Would be appreciated if someone could point me to such.

ERROR:
[root@node3 geode-benchmarks]# java -cp build/libs/geode-benchmarks-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.org.apache.geode.cache.benchmark.RangeQueryWithIndexBenchmark

Error: Could not find or load main class com.org.apache.geode.cache.benchmark.RangeQueryWithIndexBenchmark
This operation is abnormal on the system

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to benchmark the read/write performance of Geode, I think you should look at [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB). The benchmark you referred to is a micro benchmark for testing internals of Geode.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and share  . The problem has been settled